How can I use vba to get Excel to take an action right after the Developer tab button is pressed?
I'm trying to program a scratch Excel spreadsheet that students can open in a testing situation, use for calculations, but cannot save so they can't share their calculations or the content with students in a later class.
I have vba that will start with an xlVeryHidden tab, unhide it, let them work problems on it, and intercepts the save with
Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
so they can't save the file. As a precaution, I also rename it and save it as password protected when they open it.
However, if a clever student enters design mode, they can disable scripts, delete the password, and save the visible file.
Can I disable Design Mode? I can make the Developer tab not visible, but anyone who knows about Design Mode can re enable the Developer tab.
Absent disabling Design Mode, all I really need to do is to xlVeryHidden the worksheet tab when the Developer tab in the ribbon is opened and before scripts are disabled with Design Mode..
Can this be done with vba? Any suggestions?

This is never going to work.  Consider: Excel can be started with macros disabled.  VBA security is not secure at all.  Once someone has accessed your hidden sheets with macros disabled they are free to copy them at will

Apart from starting Excel with macros disabled one could access VBE by pressing Alt-F11. You would also need to disable this keyboard shortcut.

Probably the best you could do would be to lock the VBA project.
Open the VBA Editor and go to Tools > VBAProject Properties > Protection. Select Lock project for viewing, enter a password and click OK:

(You will need to have some VBA present for this to work, and have saved the project as an .xlsm file, but presumably you already have given you are using VBA already.)
If you now save the file, close and restart Excel and then re-open your file, you shouldn't be able to access the VBA project without the password.
Note that this is not totally secure, depending on how clever your clever students are.
Side note (re your original question): you can see the available Excel-level events on the pages starting here. I don't believe there's any way to trap menu selections (though I'm not certain of it).
(And of course it is not difficult to copy data from an Excel sheet, so even this will probably not achieve your end goal, which is probably unrealistic unfortunately.)
